# What are the proper etiquette to follow while referring to holy names?

Tags: halal-haram, practical-islam, salawat, respect

I have seen that there are some practices which are followed while referring to holy names or holy things. For example, I have seen many people do this:

> ... Prophet Mohammad (May Allah please be upon him)...

Why do we do this? What is this called? Is it haram to not do this?

Comment: What do you mean by holy names?

Comment: @Medi1Saif Names like Prophet Mohammad (p.b.u.h)